# What is the Windows terminal command to check if a program is running?

Tags: powershell

I would like to create a Windows script that checks if a program "anyprogram.exe" is running. If the condition is true, it ends the process of that program.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process) cmdlet in combination with [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process):

```bash
# Note: Do NOT include ".exe" in the process name.
Get-Process -Name anyprogram -ErrorAction Ignore | Stop-Process
```

Note that `Stop-Process` *forcefully* stops (kills) a process, without giving it a chance to shut down gracefully.

- [GitHub issue #13664](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13664) discusses how graceful termination could be implemented as well.

If you need *graceful* termination - which *may or may not be honored* by the target process, however - use the standard Windows `taskkill.exe` utility (whose `/f` switch can be used to request forceful termination):

```bash
Get-Process -Name anyprogram -ErrorAction Ignore |
  ForEach-Object { taskkill /pid $_.Id }
```

If - potentially forceful - termination must be *guaranteed*, try graceful termination first, then - after a timeout - fall back to forceful termination - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71803366/45375).

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-Process | Select-Object ProcessName | Where { $_.ProcessName -eq "anyprogram" }).Count -gt 0
```

Gets a list of processes running, filters on the name, counts the number of programs running with that name. If that number is greater than zero then the return value is true. If that number is zero then the return value is false.

A word of caution: omit the .exe extension in the comparison `$_.ProcessName -eq "anyprogram"` because `Get-Process` omits the ".exe" extension from results.

Comment: See also https://craigforrester.com/posts/powershell-list-running-desktop-apps/

Comment: Your answer will help me to add to the answers of other colleagues. Thanks also!

Answer (score 0):

I've done things within this realm years ago but I've been so heavily into my Mac world now that I'm hoping this is up to date enough or helpful.

Closing an app "gracefully" with WM_CLOSE:

```
$src = @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public static class Win32 {
    public static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $src
$zero = [IntPtr]::Zero
$p = @(Get-Process Notepad)[0]
[Win32]::SendMessage($p.MainWindowHandle, [Win32]::WM_CLOSE, $zero, $zero) > $null
```

Also, I found this post I had bookmarked, which just might be helpful in the sense of the "checking to see" if the app is running.
[Stack Overflow: Continuously check if a process is running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59775835/12836123)

Comment: Your approach was different, and gave me an insight about other possible applications.
Thank you very much!